# Redirect a www.domain to http://domain

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

i have a website http://mywebsite.tld , i would like to redirect www.mywebsite.tld to http://mywesite.tld (so www=>non-www)

(to prevent duplicate content)

I have read a lot of explication but for the moment no one work.

So this is my configuration maybe someone can help me.

1.my directories.

**/var/www/linktags** for my website.

in /var/www/ i have at root differents directories for differents website and 
1 index.html ("it works !" file)

2.my site-enabled file called "linktags"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName link-tags.com
    ServerAdmin cedric.duma@gmail.com
    #ServerName http://www.link-tags.com
    ########## Directory ##########
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html index.htm
    DocumentRoot /var/www/linktags

    <Directory />
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>


    ########## Alias ##########

    ########## Log Directives ##########
    ErrorLog /var/www/linktags/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/linktags/logs/access.log vhost_combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

Then my default file still in sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

1. In my **/var/www/linktags**

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [C]

RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

This is the default file generated by wordress i guess.

As you can see i tried some rewriterules , but nothing happened

I think there is some mistakes beetwen the linktags file in sites-enabled and my htaccess.

In my OVH manger of my dedicated server i have this conf for my DNS :

```
.link-tags.com NS ns106.ovh.net
.link-tags.com NS dns106.ovh.net
.link-tags.com MX 1 redirect.ovh.net
.link-tags.com  A  xx.xx.xx.xx
www.link-tags.com CNAME link-tags.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT: Create a `ServerAlias` in `VirtualHost` entry for www**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName link-tags.com
    ServerAlias www.link-tags.com
    ServerAdmin cedric.duma@gmail.com
    #ServerName http://www.link-tags.com
    ########## Directory ##########
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html index.htm
    DocumentRoot /var/www/linktags

    <Directory />
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ########## Alias ##########

    ########## Log Directives ##########
    ErrorLog /var/www/linktags/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/linktags/logs/access.log vhost_combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

**PS:** Make sure you use non-www domain in your WP's settings also.

Comment: i just tried you solution , buy still not work. I replaced my .htaccess file with yours and i cheked in wordpress  general settings the url of the wordpress site and the url of the site : http://link-tags.com
When i access to www.link-tags.com i'm still on the "it works" page

Comment: Just realized that you have 2 different `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setup in your virtual host entries for www and non-www? Is there any special reason for this? Both `www.link-tags.com` and `link-tags.com` should be pointing to same DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: can you explain where you find 2 document_root ? i dont understand what you mean :)

Comment: See you have 2 separate entries of `VirtualHost` for `link-tags.com` and `www.link-tags.com`. I have edited my answer to show you to include `ServerAlias www.link-tags.com` line in your main entry and remove entry for `www.link-tags.com`.

Comment: ok i see you added the Serveralias line , but i dont see where you removed the second entry (i think i'm blind ^^) . Do you mean in the default sites-enabled file ? i'm sorry with my stupid questions :)

Comment: I think other one where you have `DocumentRoot /var/www` is probably your default entry. You can leave that as is if you add `ServerAlias` line as shown above. Don't forget to restart Apache after this change.

Comment: Ok i added the serverAlias line , saved and reload my apache2. Now when i try to access to www.link-tags.com im correctly redirected to http://link-tags.com. Las question , is it a real redirection ? I would to index for referencement the both www. and http: , but i dont want to make duplicate content.

Comment: Because of `R=301` this is permanent redirection and search engines will also honor this and will not show any result of www URLs.